# How to make dynamic URLs with Django

Tags: django

my new project needs to fetch URLs from database. Example:

Backend add Categorys and URLs should work like:

www.example.com/hardware

if I make in Backend a new subcategory:

www.example.com/hardware/notebooks

If I add a article:

ww.example.com/hardware/notebooks/lenovo-e410 or articlenumbers.

But I didnt find out where I can add urls from SQL Queries.

Comment: May I kindly suggest your do the whole official Django tutorial, then browse the relevant parts of the official doc ? All of this is explained, so there's no point in repeating it here. Hint: you don't "add urls from SQL queries", you do SQL queries based on arguments captured from url patterns and passed to your views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I didnt find out where I can add urls from SQL Queries.

You don't need to; You should create *fixed* **patterns** after your *dynamic* URLs.

So in your **urls.py**:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('/<str:category>/', views.hardware),
    path('/<str:category>/<str:subcategory>/', views.subcategory),
    path('/<str:category>/<str:subcategory>/<str:article>/', views.article),
]
```

or if you prefer to just have URLs for your `articles`, remove the first two patterns.

Then in the corresponding views for each pattern, you should **look up your database** for the urls.

Answer (score 1):

I think you haven't gone through Django tutorial, I request you to go through the tutorial given at  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/#write-your-first-view

Add the following pattern to urls.py

```
# urls.py

from django.urls import path


urlpatterns = [
    path('/<str:category>/<str:product>/'),
]
```

```
# views.py

def product_page_view(request, category, product):
    # ... your stuffs
```

Read about Django URLs at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/

Comment: How do you do this with class-based views?